# Blank pie charts in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a series of pie charts in Tableau. They are filtered by person. Some people do not have data for some of the pie charts. For example, person 1 might have pie chart a, b, d, but not pie chart c. When this is the case, pie chart c disappears. I would like for pie chart c to show up but be blank. This is to emphasize the fact that there is no data on c for person 1. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: all these pie charts are in the same worksheet or are they in separate worksheets?

Comment: The same worksheet @Fabio Fantoni

Comment: I would also like to know how to keep the same legend for each person. The legend also auto-updates to exclude any tables/categories that are not present, but I would like it to keep all the tables/categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, missing data can't be displayed, so assuming you have 3 pie charts, A-B-C, if someone has no data for second pie chart, he/she will see A-C instead of A-#-C (# for blank).

The best workaround may be splitting those 3 charts in 3 separate worksheets.
Doing so, you could deliver a more straight forward message playing with tiled and floating objects when it come to build your dashboard.

Like in the following quick example, you may want to use tiled text with "no data" text/image putting the chart above it as a floating object.

[image]

Comment: Is there a similar issue with the legend? Can I get a category to show up in the legend even if a person doesn't have that category?

Comment: Also, do you have a link to a tutorial on how to do what you did in the above response?

Comment: regarding the legend, I would create a worksheet not filtered by your filtering criteria in order to always display the "full" legend.

Comment: no need for link or tutorial: just drag a text (tiled) in the dashboard, than click on the floating selector and drag your worsheet upon it. anyway check the link for a basic anderstanding (if needed for tiled vs floating): https://www.tableau.com/drive/floating-versus-tiled-dashboards

Comment: How can you use the legend of a worksheet without having to use the full worksheet?

Comment: just make the worksheet floating and move it "outside" (X,Y position in the layout pane) your dashboard; for instance your dashboard has 800px width, let the worksheet have x=801

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a while, I have discovered there is a simpler way! Go to your sheet, go to analysis, go to table layout, then click show empty columns. :)