# Tableau text table zero records

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am using the text table option to visualize a KPI on Tableau Dashboard (one figure visualization).
I have a filter on , and occasionally the filter will filter out all underlying record.
Is there an option to have the text tablev visualise an alternative text or "none" instead of just becoming just blank?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the field you're using is a **dimension**, you can simply right-click it on the value or on the fields window (to the left) and select "Edit aliases...", changing the 'null' alias to whatever you want.

If the field is a **measure** (numeric value), you will have to create a calculated field with a structure like:

```
IF [Field] = NULL
THEN "Field is empty"
ELSE STR([Field])
END
```

Comment: I do not get this to work. I am using two fields, one field is the filtering field , 0 and 1. I filter all 1s but the dataset only contains 1. and the other field i want to do a count on

Answer (score 0):

Once you're filtering out data, no data can be visualized and that's why you get the blank spot instead of your table/chart.

One way to bypass this problem could be building a dashboard with a **tiled** text object with "No data" and then you can put above it your worksheet in **floating** mode.

Try to see something really similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998981/blank-pie-charts-in-tableau/68999767#68999767).